# Grails discriminator -column of ids point to two different classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Can't seem to figure out how to choose a what a column points to using discriminators

```
class Groups{

   String groupCode
  static mapping{
      discriminator value:"1", formula:"case   
     when group_codein ('SLT','DDG') then 0 else 1 end", type:"integer"
   }

 }

class SupportLiveTraining extends Groups{
         static mapping{
             discriminator value:"0"
        }
     StaffSupportGroup group

  }

 class PurchaseSupport extends Groups{
         static mapping{
             discriminator value:"1"
      }
  CustomerSupportGroup group

}
```

I get error "return type of ...SupportLiveTraining getGroup() is incompatible with Groups.getGRoup()"